# How to display "NO DATA" message

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard with multiple sheets. I want to display "NO DATA" message when no record are returned for each sheet.

I've seen a solution ([NO DATA message](https://community.tableau.com/thread/117160?keywords=%22NO%20DATA%22%20message)) where you create a text box and float it then push to the background and when there is no data in the front sheet then the back sheet will display the "NO DATA" message. The problem with this is both front and back sheets have to be "Floating". I want to show the "NO DATA" message when the front sheets are not "Floating". Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: The tiled layer is by definition the bottom layer. So you can't have a tiled component on a dashboard that is in front of anything. There may be other ways to get similar effects

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but you could just write a caption, "if this is blank, there is no data". When nothing is in the view, the caption is pushed to the top near the sheet title.

[image]